# How to have my Oracle PL/SQL block update all entries related to the row_ids referenced by my cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I currently have a Oracle stored procedure that is taking data from tables. The problem is I am aggregating /grouping , and I don't want to grab the IDs otherwise that will throw the grouping off. I want to update a column called 'correlated_flag_id' to '1' (done) in the value table after ive inserted the aggregated/grouped result set. I only want to grab IDs that are correlated to the 
values that my first cursor grabbed to derive the results. Below is my attempt (which I don't think is correct):

```
 Create or Replace PROCEDURE PROC is
 CURSOR c1 is
        select sum(v.value_tx) as sum_of_values
      , max(v.create_dt) as latest_create_dt
      , v.data_date
          from value v
      group by v.data_date, max(v.create_dt)
 BEGIN
 Open c1;
 LOOP
         Fetch c1 into l_var;
                insert into value (value_id, value_tx, create_dt, data_date)
                           values (null, l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.latest_create_dt, l_var.data_Date);
 END LOOP;
 Close c1;
commit;
--- the bottom is not correct, but i've reached a roadblock
Update value
   set correlated_flag_id = 777
 where value_id in (select v.value_id from value where trunc(create_dt) <> trunc(sysdate)) (???));
 commit;
 END PROC;
```

Thanks in advance and please let me know if there is any more details that I need to provide.

Comment: So your value table doesn't have a primary key? Looks like you're sort of using value_id as the primary key, except where it's null and then it's null + data_date as the primary key? But you want to set the flag ID for all those created on a day other than today... Is creating a temp table with the ID's you wish to update as you go a possibility in this scenario?

Comment: I have a primary key, i have a trigger generating a value_id in sequence automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- cursor's select is kind of wrong; why are you grouping by a MAX function? It isn't allowed here
- switch to cursor FOR loop as it is easier to maintain. You don't have to open a cursor, fetch, **exit** the loop (which you did not do at all), close the cursor
- I'm not sure what VALUE_930 table is doing here, you never mentioned it
- your words say "update correlated ID to 1", while code says "update it to 777"
- don't commit in a procedure; let caller decide whether it should be done
- I'd suggest you to either use a tool which offers code formatting, or format it yourself. Your procedure is not a result of a flood, so don't treat it that way

Finally, here's a suggestion which might (or might not) work as we don't have your tables nor data, but - at least - looks decent.

```
create or replace procedure proc is
begin
  for cur_r in (select v.data_date,
                       sum(v.value_tx) as sum_of_values,
                       max(v.create_dt) as latest_create_dt
                from value v
                group by v.data_date)
  loop
    insert into value (value_id, value_tx, create_dt, data_date)
      values (null, cur_r.sum_of_values, cur_r.latest_create_dt, cur_r.data_date);

    update value set
      correlated_flag_id = 777
      where data_date = cur_r.data_date;
  end loop;
end proc;
/
```